# Alignment of labels in piecewise linear Tikz plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following code to draw a piecewise linear function and label it.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
func(\x)= (\x<=4) * (50)   +
 and (\x>=4, \x<7) * (49.999 - 2*(\x-4))     +
 and (\x>=7,  \x<=10) * (42-10*(\x-7)) ;
  }
]    \begin{axis}[ticks=none,
axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
ymin=20, ymax=60, ytick={}, ylabel=$x_D(t)$,
xmin=0, xmax=12, xtick={}, xlabel=$t$,
]
\addplot[blue, domain=0:10]{func(x)};
\filldraw (38,380) circle (1pt) node [right,font=\tiny] {$(t_B, x_D $)};
\filldraw (67,325) circle (1pt) node [right,font=\tiny] {$(t_C, x_D^\prime$)};
\filldraw (92,83) circle (1pt) node [right,font=\tiny] {$(t_D, 0$)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have three problems:

1. Instead of three nice piecewise linear segments, I get a slight tilt between the first two lines.
2. The `filldraw` coordinates are extremely difficult to find, I have to use trial and error - is there any way to directly map them to the actual axis 
   coordinates?
3. The last label `$(t_D,0)$` goes inside and it is barely visible.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you let pgfplots place the markers?

Comment: @percusse: How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, whe plotting piecewise functions, you have to plot the function **twice** at corner points since two different formulas are used. For example you plotted at `x=4,5`. The plot should have been plotted at `x=3.99,4.01` (or twice at 4 with the different formulas). So I modified the code to manually place the samples using `samples at` option.

Also in this code, if the sample lies exactly on 4, both formulas get executed. You should probably change one of the inequality to strict inequality (like you have done with 7).

Also there was some continuity issue in your formulas them selves (unless that was intentional). I have corrected that also. Always evaluate and see at the corner points if the left formula and right formula match in value (if you want piecewise *continuous* functions).

To place labels at corners, I used the axis coordinate system using `axis cs`. This option uses the axes to define the coordinates rather than the default tikz coordinates.

Note that the last label disappearing problem is currently fixed by changing `ymin` option. There may be better way.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
func(\x)= (\x<=4) * (50)   +
 and (\x>=4, \x<7) * (50 - 2*(\x-4))     +
 and (\x>=7,  \x<=10) * (44-10*(\x-7)) ;
  }
]    \begin{axis}[ticks=none,
axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
ymin=14, ymax=60, ytick={}, ylabel=$x_D(t)$,
xmin=0, xmax=12, xtick={}, xlabel=$t$,
]
\addplot[blue, samples at ={0,1,2,3,3.99,
                           4.01, 6.99, 7.01, 10}
        ]{func(x)};
\filldraw (axis cs: 4,50) circle (1pt) node [right,font=\tiny] {$(t_B, x_D $)};
\filldraw (axis cs: 7,44) circle (1pt) node [right,font=\tiny] {$(t_C, x_D^\prime$)};
\filldraw (axis cs: 10,14) circle (1pt) node
          [above, anchor=south west, font=\tiny] {$(t_D, 0$)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image: piecewise continuous function label]

Comment: Thanks, how do I get the axis to be adjoint to the line? I want no space between the curve and the axes.

Comment: see the edit on `ymin` and `anchor = south west`

Comment: May be someone will show and example of automatic label placement. I don't have much experience with pgfplots.